# Update a JSON-backeed cache object in RoboSpice?

Tags: robospice

Is it possible to update the cached `json` of an already cached object? If so, how? Could I update the corresponding POJO and then "persist" it manullly somehow? I cannot find reference to any methods in Robospice that would allow one to do that. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that if you use the Jackson Persister from the jackson2springandroidspiceservice, you cannot as the cache is read-only but I was able to change the persisted object stored using the ORMlite module and RS returned the changed object.